# Show list of open files in UltraEdit

Tags: ultraedit

Most editors have either a dialog or a "Window" menu that allows to access any open file via a couple of keystrokes.

Where is this feature for UltraEdit?

Answer (score 0):

The open files are in menu *Window*:

[image: Screenshot of UltraEdit with menu Window open]

The keystrokes to access any open file is then <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>W</kbd>, followed by several <kbd>arrow up</kbd>s to the select the file and finally <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

---

Alternatively, use the File Tree View (on the left in the screenshot above). If not already enabled, enable it in the *View* menu, *View/Lists* -> *File Tree View*:

[image: Screenshot of UltraEdit, enabling of File Tree View]

However, I think it is only possible to use it with the mouse.

Comment: Which version/oS??  I have ubuntu and latest version of UEX for linux  There is NO window menu - that is exactly what I had been looking for